# Calculus Made Easy Exercises 15 Question 12 (Optimization)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

"A telpherage bucket of given capacity has the shape of a horizontal isosceles triangular prism with the apex underneath, and the opposite face open. Find its dimensions in order that the least amount of iron sheet may be used in its construction." How would you approach this problem?

Comment: What is the volume of the bucket?  What is the surface area (not counting the open face)?  In order to answer these questions, you have to decide what the variables are.

Comment: @BrianS I assume that the shape of the bucket corresponds to an "upside-down" version of the following image: https://www.google.com/search?q=prism+picture&client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNRy675jq_7cCqGXt7Z0SwJkM6xUpg:1576960079473&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=Zd3LOth1Z2kQ-M%253A%252Cr1vH9WXD52XrCM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kS0icdiTl27OTld_i5Bykh4ngXlgQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidqe-KysfmAhWVhJ4KHdXjDskQ9QEwB3oECAoQPA#imgrc=Zd3LOth1Z2kQ-M:  Suppose you let $h$ = height of the prism, $w$ = width of each triangular face of the prism, and $V$ = the **known** volume of the prism.   ...see next comment

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Did you read the last sentence of my comment?

Comment: @BrianS You then need to (1) determine the formula [$f(h,w)$] for the prism, in terms of $h$ and $w$.  This will allow you to express $h$ in terms of $w$ and $V$, where $V$ is assumed to be a known value.  Then (2) express the surface area as a function $g(h,w)$.  This should allow you to re-express $g(h,w)$ as a function $j(h)$, since you can express $w$ in terms of $h$ and $V$.  Then compute the 1st and 2nd derivatives of $j(h)$ to determine the value of $h$ that minimizes $j(h)$.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck You aren't understanding what I've said.  To answer the question, you need formulas for the surface area and the volume.  To arrive at these formulas, you must first decide what the variables are.  I have no idea what you mean by "decide them in an answer."